# Can Span<T> keep managed memory from being garbage collected?

Tags: c#, reference, garbage-collection

`Span<T>` is a `ref struct` that represents a contiguous region of arbitrary memory. It has an internal field called `_pointer` of type `ByReference<T>`, which is .NET's workaround for the lack of by-ref fields in C#/CIL and is handled specially by the JIT and type loader. My question is, because this field is `Span<T>`'s only reference to the arbitrary memory, can `Span<T>` still be guaranteed to keep any managed memory it represents alive? For example:

```
public static Span<byte> GetSpan(int length) => new byte[length];

public static void Method()
{
    var span = GetSpan(1);

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    // ...

    span[0] = 0; // Will this always succeed?
}
```

Comment: Short answer; Yes. Otherwise the type safety guarantees of the runtime would be broken.

Comment: Yes, `ByReference<T>` is internally a managed pointer (aka interior pointer), interpreted appropriately by the GC. Please refer to my articles [Managed pointers in .NET](https://tooslowexception.com/managed-pointers-in-net/) and [Ref struct (byref-like type) and ByReference (byref-like instance field)](https://tooslowexception.com/ref-struct-byref-like-type-and-byreference-byref-like-instance-field/).